# Incorrect function return when executed in loop

Tags: r, list, time-series

I have the following function:

```
funNNET <- function(dFrame,nDF,horizon,i,j){
       model_NNET <- forecast::nnetar(y = dFrame$Qty)

## Dataframe with predictions ##

  output_nnet <- list()
  output_nnet$Sales_Date = nDF$Sales_Date
  output_nnet$predNNET = as.integer(forecast(object = model_NNET, h = 
  horizon)$mean)
  output_nnet$LastYear = nDF$LastYear
  output_nnet$Combi = paste(i,j,sep = "|")

  print(output_nnet$predNNET)
  return(output_nnet)
}
```

When I execute this function in isolation, it runs perfectly and I get my result list. However, when I execute this function in loop (say foreach or lapply), I only get a date list, which is the first item of my desired output list.

Please help me out in finding what I'm missing. In case any info is required, let me know and I'll share that.

*UPDATE*

Use following command to have sample dataset

```
dFrame <- data.frame(Sales_Date = seq(as.Date("2017-12-12"),as.Date("2017-
12-30"),"days"),
Qty = c(rep(3.4,5),rep(4.2,1),rep(4.9,3),rep(3,2),rep(5.6,5),rep(7.2,3)) )

nDF <- data.frame(Sales_Date = seq(min(dFrame$Sales_Date) - 
lubridate::years(1) ,max(dFrame$Sales_Date) - lubridate::years(1),"days"),
LastYear 
=c(rep(9.4,5),rep(2.5,1),rep(6.2,3),rep(3.1,2),rep(9.5,5),rep(11.1,3)) )

horizon = 30

i = c("AHMD","BLR","MUM","DEL")
j = c("A","B","C","D")
```

Comment: Please provide some example data.

Comment: Please provide some sample data and reusable code, on how you are using this code. Lists are a bit tricky to use.

Comment: added the same.